What would fail if "second countable" is replaced by "paracompact" in the definition of manifold?
If I were to define a topological manifold to be a locally $n$-Euclidean, Hausdorff, paracompact topological space and continue to add the smooth structure based on it, what important result would fail without the assumption of second countability?
One still has the partition of unity. While one cannot embed a paracompact manifold into $\Bbb R^n$, one could embed instead to the Tychonoff cube since every such paracompact manifold is locally compact and Hausdorff, thus completely regular and Hausdorff.
Also if one just looks at manifolds with at most countably many connected components then there is no need of requiring second-countability. So why do we rule out manifolds with infinitely many connected components?

Paracompact and at most countably many connected components will imply 2nd countable.

@MoisheKohan That is correct and is mentioned in my last paragraph.

We rule out manifolds with uncountable many components. For instance so that a continuous bijection between manifolds was a homeomorphism. So that if a Lie group $G$ acts transitively on a manifold $M$, then $M$ is homeomorphic to $G/G_x$.
